# eloquent casting array in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, api, postman

I use eloquent attribute casting for Report model

### my model

[image]

### my controller

[image]

### my response in postman

[image]

but I want to have this response like this when $report is exist for if condition

```
array[
   {
     "userId" : 2,
     "reportReason" : "abuse",
     "selectItem":"2"
   },
   {
     "userId" : 2,
     "reportReason" : "abuse",
     "selectItem":"2"
   },
   {
     "userId" : 2,
     "reportReason" : "abuse",
     "selectItem":"2"
   }
]
```

I mean when new $detail insert into report_details save after first array not not inside it

Comment: please post codes, instead of images

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `array_push` do `array_merge`

```
  dd(array_merge($temp,$detail));
```

Comment: noting happen with array_merge() .how add second array after first array no inside

Comment: I found the problem . By putting $data when thhe first report create into brucket means [$data] it is working